# Subtract /Loop through rows in HIVE Query

Tags: sql, date, group-by, hive, hiveql

I have a data in table like below

```
ID  status      timestamp
ABC login       1/1/2020 12:00
ABC lock        1/1/2020 13:19
ABC unlock      1/1/2020 13:52
ABC Disconnect  1/1/2020 15:52
ABC Reconnect   1/1/2020 15:55
ABC lock        1/1/2020 16:25
ABC unlock      1/1/2020 16:30
ABC logoff      1/1/2020 17:00
ABC login       2/1/2020 12:00
ABC lock        2/1/2020 13:19
ABC unlock      2/1/2020 13:52
ABC lock        2/1/2020 16:22
ABC logoff      2/1/2020 17:00
```

I need to find the effective working hours of an employee on a particular date for which he has really worked. Meaning sum of total time minus timings when the status was lock, disconnect.

Example: for employee ABC on 01-JAN-2020, his system was ideal between 13:19 - 13:52(33 minutes) and again from 15:52 - 15:55(3 minutes). 
Hence, out of total working hour i.e... 5hrs (time between login and log off time) his effective time would be 5hr - 36 minutes = 4hr24 minutes. 
Similarly for 01-FEB-2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions, then aggregation:

```
select 
    id,
    to_date(timestamp) timestamp_day,
    sum(case when status in ('lock', 'disconnect') then - duration else duration end) / 60 / 60 hours_worked
from (
    select t.*, 
        lead(timestamp) over(partition by id order by timestamp)
            - unix_timestamp(timestamp) status_duration
    from mytable t
) t
group by id, to_date(timestamp)
order by id, to_date(timestamp)
```

In the subquery, we use `lead()` to retrieve the timestamp of the "next" action, so we can compute the duration of the current step. The outer query aggregates by employee and day, and do the final computation of working hours according to your business rule.